# Move multiple faces towards single point

Tags: transforms, edit-mode

I want to achieve similar effect to scaling multiple faces but I don't want to scale individual faces.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A way to get the result is to select one of the faces at the end you want to move and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and select *Hook to New Object*, repeat for the other faces you want to move.

Go into object mode and select the empties that were just created. Enable the manipulate pivot points option (nice if we had this in edit mode) and scale the empties until the faces are where you want them.

[image: manipulate origins]

[image: example]

Once the ends are in place, apply the hook modifiers and delete the empties.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I can scale them normaly then switch to Pivot>Individual Origins and scale back the faces without moving them. And if I want to be super precise I can always check previous scaled value in the log but still, any option to do this in single step will be cool  :)

[image]

Comment: This approach seem tedious. It also doesn't cover scaling to 0, which would be useful, when you want the faces to meet in their center.

Comment: you could also use the skin modifier to draw the structure instead of extruding polygons individually. Add a couple of mirror modifiers and you only have to work with one 'pipe'

Comment: Yea, but it's still faster then creating empty for each face and it's face count independent. Now I have only 4 but what if I had 20? Mirrors are good if you know that final shape will be symmetrical but I don't know that.